# Dungeon generation in Scala

Tags: beginner, game, scala

I've recently begun learning Scala, and while I've run into its concepts before (immutability, tuples, first-class functions) I'm not sure whether I'm using the language how it's supposed to be used. My learning project is going to be a simple little dungeon crawler, and while you can see the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/ogham/InfiniteDungeon/blob/5c76ccf8ff089c5e6588339b093e0e6f6c32e245/src/main/scala/infinite/dungeon/LevelBuilder.scala), I'm copying a simplified version here below.

Example output looks like this, where ?s are potential rooms and #s are actual rooms:

```
     ?     
 ??  #  ?  
?## ### #  
  ### ####?
  ?? ## #  
      ##   
      #    
    ?##?   
     ??
```

And here's how it's implemented:

```
class LevelBuilder(random: Random) {

  /** Mapping of positions to the rooms at them. */
  var rooms: mutable.Map[(Int, Int), Room] = mutable.Map()

  /** List of areas where rooms could be generated. */
  var possibilities: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List()

  /**
   * Adds a new room to the map at the given position, and adds the available
   * positions around it to the possibilities list.
   */
  def addRoom(position: (Int, Int), room: Room): LevelBuilder = {
    rooms += position -> room

    // First, remove the room from the list of possibilities.
    possibilities = possibilities.filter(pos => pos != position).++(around(position))

    // Next, add the positions around that one to the list...
    possibilities = possibilities ++ around(position)

    // ...but then remove all of the ones around *those*, so no two paths will ever link up.
    possibilities = possibilities.filter(pos => roomPossibility(around(pos).count(p => rooms.contains(p))) && !rooms.contains(pos))

    this
  }

  /**
   * Determine whether a room should be build based on its number of neighbours.
   */
  private def roomPossibility(neighboursCount: Int): Boolean = {
    neighboursCount <= 1
  }

  /** Adds the given number of rooms to the level. */
  def addRooms(number: Int): LevelBuilder = {
    for (i <- 0 to number) {
      var index = random.nextInt(possibilities.length)        // Pick a random room from the possibilites list...
      addRoom(possibilities(index), Room.randomRoom(random))  // ...and add it
    }

    this
  }

  /** Return the four positions around the given one. */
  def around(position: (Int, Int)): Seq[(Int, Int)] = {
    List(
      (position._1 + 1, position._2),
      (position._1 - 1, position._2),
      (position._1, position._2 - 1),
      (position._1, position._2 + 1)
    )
  }

  /** Return a build layout of this level. */
  def build(): mutable.Map[(Int, Int), Room] = rooms.clone()

  /**
   * Print out a grid view of the level so far, showing both possibilities and
   * created rooms.
   */
  def debug() {
    val miny: Int = rooms.minBy(_._1._2)._1._2 min possibilities.minBy(_._2)._2  // there's got to be a better way to write this
    val maxy: Int = rooms.maxBy(_._1._2)._1._2 max possibilities.maxBy(_._2)._2
    val minx: Int = rooms.minBy(_._1._1)._1._1 min possibilities.minBy(_._1)._1
    val maxx: Int = rooms.maxBy(_._1._1)._1._1 max possibilities.maxBy(_._1)._1

    for (j <- miny to maxy) {
      for (i <- minx to maxx) {
        if (possibilities.contains((i, j))) {
          print("?")
        }
        else if (rooms.contains((i, j))) {
          print("#")
        }
        else {
          print(" ")
        }
      }
      println("")
    }
  }
}
```

So what do you all think? I've only been using Scala for a few days, so I'm interested to learn things like whether I should prefer using operators to methods, or whether there's a certain style of variable names I should be using, or anything like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking quickly over your code here are a couple of the changes I would make:

First, I would add a class to your application (probably within the levelbuilder.scala file) that encapsulates the (Int, Int) tuple you are using throughout this code snippet. E.g.

```
    case class Pos(x: Int, y: Int) {
      def neighborhood: List[Pos] = {
        Pos(x + 1, y) :: Pos(x - 1, y) :: Pos(x, y - 1) :: Pos(x, y + 1) :: Nil
      }
    }
```

When building this class I also took the chance to rewrite the method called `around(pos: (Int, Int))` from the `LevelBuilder` class to a more concise method which I've called neighborhood just to differentiate it.

Also, if you haven't had a chance to read-up on case classes in Scala, now would be a good time to do so :) They provide a lot of functionality with just a few lines of code.

Now you may declare the `LevelBuilder` fields `rooms` and `possibilities` like so:

```
    val rooms = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Pos, Room]()
    var possibilities = List[Pos]()
```

One place that these changes drastically add to readability in your code is in the `debug()` method:

```
    def debug(): Unit = {
      val possibilePos = rooms.keys ++ possibilities

      val minY = possiblePos.minBy(_.y).y
      val maxY = possiblePos.maxBy(_.y).y
      val minX = possiblePos.maxBy(_.x).x
      val maxX = possiblePos.maxBy(_.x).x

      // print map 
    }
```

Notice also that I changed `miny` to `minY` etc.